# onsubmit function not executing javascript function

Tags: javascript

I know this question has been asked, but I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on. I have a very simple onsubmit function that should execute when I run in my html. I have no problem running oninput, but not onsubmit.

The extremely strange thing is, that the exact same html/javascript runs fine in jsfiddle. Any ideas?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CheckLogin()
        {
           alert('I should work');   
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <form name="login" id="login" method="POST" onsubmit="return CheckLogin();">
        <input type="submit" value="Test" name="test" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Is It not the browser? https://codepen.io/paulodiogo/pen/NwwNzG

Comment: I guess it is a problem of when your `script` is loaded in your html. Maybe you can consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

Comment: The ordering shouldn't matter in this case, because you are calling a function that is not referencing DOM elements. What are you using for editing and trying this out?

Comment: Also, no need to say `onsubmit="return CheckLogin();"` you just need to call the function - `onsubmit="CheckLogin();"`

Comment: It works in the SO code snippets also.  Can you share how to reproduce the problem you're seeing?  i.e. what setup (browser, code input, etc) make it not work?

Comment: Not sure what's going on. If I remove the submit input and add <input type="button" onclick="foo()" /> this works fine. I'm on chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit). This same browser works on jsfiddle, so I can't imagine that's the issue.

Comment: Changed the onsubmit function to foo, and it seems to pick it up: t.onsubmit
ƒ onsubmit(event) {
  foo()
}
where t is my form element, so I'm not sure why it's never executing.